# Response.Redirect fails when Trace is turned off

Tags: asp.net, response.redirect

I have this weird thing going on in my application.

At the moment, I have `'Trace="true"` on my `aspx` directive and all `Response.Redirect()` codes are working fine. But as soon as I remove this directive, all the `Response.Redirect` go to the Home page of the site.

Any help will be appreaciated.

Here's the code:

`protected void SearchSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
Response.Redirect( "~/?view=Search+results&search=" + Server.UrlEncode(SearchText.Text), true);
}`

`protected void AdvSearchSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
string filtertype = ""; if (rbFilter.SelectedValue != "") filtertype = "&f=" + rbFilter.SelectedValue; Response.Redirect("~/?view=Search+results&search=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(advSearchText.Text) ); 
}`

Comment: Response.Redirect() by default causes an exception. Is this messing with your redirects? Try Response.Redirect(url, false).

Comment: The Trace option shouldn't impact redirects.  Can you include some code snippets, including an example of the Trace directive you're using?

Comment: My Global.asax doesn't redirect to the home page   :   void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }

Comment: Here is my code snippet:  protected void SearchSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          Response.Redirect(
                "~/?view=Search+results&search=" + Server.UrlEncode(SearchText.Text), true);
        } protected void AdvSearchSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string filtertype = "";
            if (rbFilter.SelectedValue != "")
                filtertype = "&f=" + rbFilter.SelectedValue;
            
            Response.Redirect("~/?view=Search+results&search=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(advSearchText.Text) );
        }

Answer (score 0):

I'll bet an exception is occuring and you're being redirected to the home page via your `application_error` method in `Global.asax`.

Since `response.redirect()` aborts the thread this is the likely outcome.

Comment: My Global.Asax doesn't redirect to the home page: void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs

    }